# The best word to describe "not easy to fall"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Based on my research, I have several options (all of them come with problem).

- Stable (I don't want to have 'resist to change' meaning)
- Firm (I don't want to have 'resist to change' & 'standing still' meaning)
- Steady (I don't want to have 'standing still' meaning)

I want to describe something that moves, but not easy to fall/stop by outside stimulus.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a two-word phrase that aptly modifies "stability" and captures the concept succinctly i.e., **DYNAMIC STABILITY**

> **Q: What is the definition of dynamic stability in human movement? We say a state is stable, what then is dynamic stability?**
>
> **A**: **Equilibrium means moving without acceleration. Balance is the control of equilibrium. Stability is the resistance to perturbation.**
>
> [**dynamic stability**](http://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_dynamic_stability_definition_in_human_movement_We_say_a_state_is_stable_what_is_dynamic_stability1)
>
> Link to article: [**Assessing the stability of human locomotion: a review of current measures**](http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/10/83/20120999.full)

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's accurate for academic purpose. But my purpose is on product branding. So I need the one word version. So, sorry, not yet an answer... :)

Actually, I need some single words that would define the word "Agile". I already have 'Fast' & 'Flexible' in hand.

I believe it still need to describe 'the uneasiness to fall' ('fast' and 'flexible' already describe the movement).

Comment: "Back to the drawing board" as they say. If you would edit these additional factors into your OP it will help others to provide you with good suggestions.

Comment: And what is the product?

Answer (score 1):

Infallible is metaphorical, but it may suit the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

*Stable* is indeed an appropriate word for something that won't fall over.  However, if you want to convey a stronger sense of motion, you could say

- self-stabilizing
- self-balancing
- self-righting

For example, [self-stabilizing unicycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_unicycle), [self-balancing scooters](http://www.airwheel.net/q3.html), and [self-righting cups](http://www.google.com/patents/US4096966) exist.

Answer (score 1):

*Steady* is just fine, as it doesn't necessarily imply standing still. Something can move steadily.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is **resilient**

From Merriam-Webster:

> a :  capable of withstanding shock without permanent deformation or
>   rupture
>
> b :  tending to recover from or adjust easily to misfortune or change

It is a word with very positive connotations, being used to describe a return to good health:

"The local economy is remarkably resilient."